# <React useRef> When a component was called twice in its parent, How does the ref work

Tags: reactjs, use-ref

I was reading the react docs, there's this example which I think was really bizzare:
[challenge_2](https://beta.reactjs.org/learn/synchronizing-with-effects#fetching-data)
MyInput.js

```js
import { useEffect, useRef } from 'react';

export default function MyInput({ shouldFocus, value, onChange }) {
  const ref = useRef(null);

  // TODO: call focus() only if shouldFocus is true.
  useEffect(() => {
    ref.current.focus();
  }, []);

  return (
    <input
      ref={ref}
      value={value}
      onChange={onChange}
    />
  );
}
```

App.js

```js
import { useState } from 'react';
import MyInput from './MyInput.js';

export default function Form() {
  const [show, setShow] = useState(false);
  const [firstName, setFirstName] = useState('Taylor');
  const [lastName, setLastName] = useState('Swift');
  const [upper, setUpper] = useState(false);
  const name = firstName + ' ' + lastName;
  return (
    <>
      <button onClick={() => setShow(s => !s)}>{show ? 'Hide' : 'Show'} form</button>
      <br />
      <hr />
      {show && (
        <>
          <label>
            Enter your first name:
            <MyInput
              value={firstName}
              onChange={e => setFirstName(e.target.value)}
              shouldFocus={true}
            />
          </label>
          <label>
            Enter your last name:
            <MyInput
              value={lastName}
              onChange={e => setLastName(e.target.value)}
              shouldFocus={false}
            />
          </label>
          <p>Hello, <b>{upper ? name.toUpperCase() : name}</b></p>
        </>
      )}
    </>
  );
}
```

In this challenge, the `<MyInput>` was called twice in `App.js`, to render 2 input doms, which was refed in the implementation of `<MyInput>`.
The thing is, when running this code, only the **last** input will be focused, I thought refs were independent between components, so I was expecting both inputs will be focused. Could someone please explain why this happen?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p3D4u.png)

Comment: Its not related to react, you are expecting multiple elements to be focused, which is not possible by design. So in this specific case, the latest focus event will be triggered. Search for "Can multiple HTML elements receive focus at the same time?" for more context.

Comment: A good reference to start your research is MDN docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/focus

Comment: @DennisVash Wow! That's very helpful, you just saved my day! Thanks a lot!